# Tool to help deploy Java Servlet web app server software in a customer environment?

Tags: database, web-server, configuration-management, nginx

I am using [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) currently to deploy a web application. Reading up on Ansible it seems like this is not what Ansible was designed for. Is there another type of tool that should be used for something like this?

This would be used to install/configure nginx, tomcat, database and search components. Either all on the same box, with a distributed database on multiple nodes. Or dedicated UI/Search/Database nodes in a cluster which can be manged from itself, including configuration changes and upgrades.

Could be as few as 1 server up to maybe 20 servers in most cases.

Comment: Ansible seems to be a good choice for this, I would say. Apart from what you have read, is there anything that you think Ansible does not do in the best possible way?